# Groovy: handle different date formats and conversions

Tags: date, groovy

I am a newbie to Groovy. I have the following dates in my db:

```
1:00 AM

10:00 PM
```

`1:00AM` (same as above without space)

```
1:00:00

13:00

13:00:00
```

I want them to be scanned and converted to the same format. is there any simple way in Groovy that I can opt for. (These are stored as strings in a db).
Lets say I want all dates to be in `AM | PM` format.

I am able to differentiate between formats using regex matching but still confused how to convert them.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Java 8, you could construct a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional patterns covering each of your use cases:

```
def times = [
    '1:00 AM',
    '10:00 PM',
    '1:00AM',
    '1:00:00',
    '13:00',
    '13:00:00'
]

import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseLenient()
            .appendPattern("[h:mm a][h:mm a][h:mma][H:mm:ss][H:mm][h:mm:SSa][hh:mm:SS a]")
            .toFormatter();

times.each {
    println LocalTime.parse(it, formatter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after writing the method  that would output the different formats for you let's call it `formatmethod()`, you can use the `subtring()`method in Groovy  with simple if statements to modify the strings, also notice how the problem is always at the end of the strings, I don't think there is any built in methods in Groovy that will automatically reformat the time for you .

```
1:00 AM -> format1

10:00 PM -> format2

1:00AM  -> format3

1:00:00 -> format4

13:00  -> format5

13:00:00 -> format6
```

**Example:**

```
if(timeString.formatmethod()==format3){
  def modifiedTimeString = timeString.substring(0,3)+" AM"; 
}
```